# How to properly store and use MySQL TIMESTAMP with different timezones?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an application that based on scheduling appointments, in an environment where a user can select their desired timezone.

After doing some research, I was convinced to use MYSQL's `TIMESTAMP` to store all dates. I *thought* that, when using `TIMESTAMP`, all dates would be converted and stored as UTC. Then, a `TIMESTAMP` column would convert to the timezone of MYSQL when pulling the date from the database.

***Below is some example code of my current setup:***

On each page, the timezones are set for PHP and MYSQL *(Based on user selection. PST for this example)*:

```
date_default_timezone_set('US/Pacific');
SET time_zone = '-08:00'
```

When putting a time into MYSQL, I would just convert a timestamp to the proper format.

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unix_timestamp);
```

When pulling form the database, I would simply use MYSQL to convert to UNIX.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) as created_at FROM `table` WHERE id=1
```

This was elegant, and seemed to work perfectly. MySQL was doing all the heavy lifting of timezone conversion for me, just by using `TIMESTAMP`. That is, Until a Daylight Savings Time happened. Now, anytime a non-UTC timezone is selected, the time is an **hour off**.

What am I doing, wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use;

```
date_default_timezone_set('US/Pacific');
SET time_zone = '-08:00'
```

...MySQL's server time zone will be one hour off from Pacific time in the summers since `PDT` is `GMT-07:00`. Instead use for example;

```
date_default_timezone_set('US/Pacific');
SET time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
```

...and MySQL's server time will support DST changes and you should get the correct time zone conversions.

Since MySQL doesn't always contain all available time zones, if the time zone `America/Los_Angeles` is missing from your system, [this page should help you install it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html).

Since you're using dynamic time zones per user, you may need some kind of lookup table to translate between MySQL and PHP time zones, so you can set them both correct per user.

Comment: I must have worded my question in a way that the community didnt like, but I am sure if they actually understood my question as you did, it would not have been closed. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store in the database the times as UTC (GMT as us English prefer)?

Then either use [CONVERT_TZ()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function in mySql or [setTimezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) in PHP.

This will enable people to look at other peoples calendar with ease and convert to their local time. Thereby nobody has a reason for being too early or too late (or on the wrong day!).

Comment: Well, I was under the assumption that MYSQL's TIMESTAMP column automatically stored all times as UTC. Which it seemed to do fine, but now for some reason after the DST that happened 2 days ago, my times are an hour off.